# Need to make this irc bot work with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

Instad of getting a respones from .downloads i want a url to triggger it and get a response back from  BeautifulSoup, Im pretty new to python and this is only like my 3rd project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import botlib
import urllib
import BeautifulSoup

class StaffBot(botlib.Bot):
    def __init__(self, server, channel, nick, password=None):
        botlib.Bot.__init__(self, server, 6667, channel, nick)

        if password != None:
            self.protocol.privmsg("nickserv", "identify" % password)
    def __actions__(self):
        botlib.Bot.__actions__(self)

        if botlib.check_found(self.data, ".downloads"):
            username = self.get_username()

            self.protocol.privmsg(self.channel, "%s: response" % username)          

if __name__ == "__main__":
    StaffBot("irc.rizon.net", "#chan", "nick").run()
```

just in-case i did that wrong.... 
http://pastebin.com/AhrssPVW

the BeautifulSoup script im using.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen("url"))
print soup.title.string
```

Edit

I kinda failed on what i was trying to say, i want to replace .downloads with say website.net/viewtopic.php. so wen someone says the website (like below) the bot replied with the page title.

```
somone>>>website.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10960                                                                                           
bot>>>WebsiteName &bull; Viewtopic - topicname
```

Comment: so when are you trying to fecth a url? currently you will not get content from `urllib.urlopen('url')` because you are passing it a string.

Comment: The url will be coming from users on my irc channel, I want to add beautifulsoup into the bot so when a users types a url from our site.   example. http://website.net/viewtopic.php will be the trigger instead of .downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you create a command for your users

```
if botlib.check_found(self.data, "!download"):
  # must be !download <url>
  url = self.data.split()[1] # < i don't know if the library adds anything else to self.data
  soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))
  print soup.title.string
```

THis requires your users include a url after the `!download` command.

so a user in the room can type `!download website.net/viewtopic.php`  Your bot will check if it is  a download command `check_found(self.data, "!download")`.  It then needs to get the download url. `split()` splits a string into a list on white space.  And the url to fetch will be the second item in the list `[1]`.  YOu can then fetch/parse that url using beautiful soup.

Comment: thats not what i ment, edited it a little more and i hope you can understand it a little bit better....